How to balance the main rotor of helicopter?
In mi17 class helicopters, the OEM had not given an option of adding weights at main rotor hub or blade tips at unit level. The blade sets are usually static balanced when received by units. Is there any way through which dynamic balancing of rotors can be performed to reduce heavy vibrations without adding extra weights. For eg, either by reducing pitch of heavier blades etc.

When I worked on UH-60 Blackhawks, we used to use a pretty expensive test set to conduct a main rotor track and balance which was pretty involved and took a couple hours to complete just the setup prior to even beginning the process.
I can't remember the name of the system, but it required that we mount a number of accelerometers, which were little chrome cylindrical units about the size of your thumb, to their brackets which were already attached to the airframe in various locations inside the cabin, inside maintenance panels, and were oriented facing in a few different directions in reference to the fuselage's centerline, but always in 90° increments.
Then we removed the avionics nose compartment's airflow inlet screen from the avionics compartment door (basically acts like the hood of a car and opens from the front upwards) to allow for a camera to be mounted in that position. This camera had two lenses, one atop the other, however one of those lenses was actually an IR emitter which was designed to project the specific frequency of IR that the other lense, the actual camera was designed to detect.
The camera was mounted to that compartment door on the precise center lin## Heading ##e of the fuselage facing forward without zero lateral toe angle, but with a pronounced upward angle to ensure the emitter and receiver lenses were centered on a defined station along the main rotor disk. If memory serves that station was about 1' to 2' from the tips of the main rotor blades. On one blade we would affix a strip of specialized reflective tape which was specifically designed to work with IR emitter and sensor camera mounted on the nose and allow the system to "see" how the main rotor disk was tracking.
Once all the required sensors were mounted at their respective locations we would run dedicated cables from each sensor, each accelerometer having a multi-lead cannon plug on the opposite end of the threaded stud used to mount them, to a common location in the forward cabin This process could take some time and wasn't something we would rush, as some of these sensors were mounted in locations which were normally inaccessible when operating, including along the exterior of the aircraft.
There was also a tail rotor camera which mounted to the upper tail pylon and faced towards the spinning tail rotor blades. As with the main rotor, one of the tail rotor paddles would be used to attach a strip of the reflective tape to give the IR emitter something to reflect off of the the camera sensor could detect it. The need to conduct a tail rotor track and balance was not nearly as common as the main rotor track and balance on account of the fully rigid design the Blackhawk was built with. It's amazing how easy and reliable machines can get when you design out most of the moving parts!
Where and how we routed these cables was critical and needed to be done in such a way that ensured that even if multiple attachment fasteners used to secure the cables to the airframe failed, that segment would not come into contact with any parts of the aircraft and cause a safety of flight issue. Yes, for some of the track and balance procedures the aircraft would be placed in an IGE hover, as well as occasionally a short maintenance flight with this test equipment installed and operating.
Once all the accelerometer and camera data cables were run, located in the forward cabin directly behind the pilot seat, usually there was nothing more to install. However there were a couple procedures which were far less common which required that we remove the access panels housing the aircraft's vibration damper assemblies (heavy weights attached to  the airframe with massive flat stainless steel springs) and I believe somehow inhibit their because operation somehow.
Behind the pilot seat where all the data cables were run was the system's brains. Every cable connected to the appropriate cannon plug connector on the face of what was called the Data Acquisition Unit (DAU) which contained the data processing hardware and programming capabilities the system was designed for. Finally a single data cable from the DAU was routed forward towards the pilot seat and connected to an input and display unit which was used as the interface for the maintenance test pilot conducting the track and balance. This unit, really a specialized computer in it's own right, was designed to be handheld or placed on the pilot's lap, but it was NOT small or light. Thinking back it measured about 20" wide, 18" tall, and 3 inches thick, had a small rectangle monochrome LCD display centered at the top of the unit's face, and was equipped with probably a dozen and a half buttons which were the type that are mounted under a single solid piece of textured flexible plastic material with each button outlined, labeled, and slightly raised.
That unit was used to input the specific characteristics of the aircraft, which type of procedure being conducted, which sensors were installed, where on the aircraft they were mounted, when to start measuring, and would provide calculated results after the test procedures, as well as what it reccommended in terms of mechanical adjustments in order to improve the results.
The tests would mostly involve the aircraft being runup to full operational speed, with the system dictating to the pilot how much power to pull in. Once the aircraft was in that configuration the pilot intiated the test on the control unit in his lap, it would collect about a minute or two worth of data, indicate to the pilot when it was finished and satisfied with the data, and the pilot would shut the aircraft down. While waiting for the rotor blades to spin down the system would conduct its calculations and produce the results in terms of "ips", which I never really understood, but more importantly it would also produce a number of different adjustments it reccommended to improve the results as it worked towards a set of results that were all within acceptable standards.
For the main rotor we had two primary means of adjusting the track and balance, vertical primary control (PC) rod adjustments and main rotor blade trailing edge trim tab adjustments. The PC rods were the far easier and less risky adjustments, involving a couple jam nuts, an adjustment tab, and some safety wire, which any adjustments made easily being reversed if needed. Plus the guidance offered by the system was unambiguous and required no special tools or skills. Making adjustments to the rotor blade trim tabs, on the other hand, was anything but clear, required either a large maintenance stand or the removal of the blade, was delicate work with potentially massive implications, and as with any metal reduced the structural integrity of the trim tab every time it was bent for an adjustment.
Usually the maintenance test pilot would run the aircraft up, shut down, read the adjustments reccommended by the system, communicate them directly to the maintenance crew, adjustments were made, rinse and repeat until the system reported the aircraft was within acceptable tolerances.
There were, however, the occasional maintenance test pilots who felt that the reccommended adjustments provided by the system were too aggressive, not aggressive enough, or the results of those adjustments could be achieved through other, better adjustments. Honestly I've seen these guys make a 3 hour process into a 30 minute process and I've seen them make a 3 hour process into a brutal multi-day marathon of insanity. Either way, when if we realized we were working with one of these "I know Best" maintenance test pilots, the mood usually suffered and frustrations were voiced!
This type of procedure and equipment was used back in the late 90's and early 2000's, so they may have a new, lighter, and more powerful system that figures out the adjustments needed in one run. Hope this answers your question at least to some degree.

The system you are referring is vibrex. But any crude way of doing the iteration, if the maintenance crew is not having this equipment and setup? Can we state that, heavier blades should have lesser length of PC so as to reduce drag?
